# Is this dialogue idiomatic: - How do you often cook potatoes? - Often I just bake them

Tags: grammar, adverbs, syntax

Is this dialogue idiomatic:

-- How do you often cook potatoes? 
-- Often I just bake them.

Comment: Source of text please.  What is your specific concern about it?  Why do you doubt that it is idiomatic  What would you suggest as a possible fix?  Please see the [ask].

Comment: It's grammatical but almost a non-sequitur. It's not an answer to the question, it's an oblique shift of subject.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's grammatical and understandable, but not idiomatic.

In the question, "Often" is not usually used in that way. We can ask "How often", but when the frequency is not the focus, we don't usually say "often". We can say "always", "sometimes" or "usually", but not "often", "frequently" or "rarely". I have no explanation for this.

In the answer, "Often" is more acceptable. If the question were just "How do you cook potatoes", then I would find "often" fairly natural in the answer, making the point that I do not **always** bake them. I think I'd probably say "usually", though.

Comment: Yes - "How do you usually cook potatoes?" (What is the method you most commonly use?)